# Get ids and names of parent categories

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category

How can I get the ids and the names of a group of parent categories? I got an array of ids that belong to a product but I want to show their parent id names too.

With this code I get all current ids:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

This returns an array:

```
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 25 [2] => 66 [3] => 78 [4] => 79 [5] => 80 [6] => 81 [7] => 82 [8] => 83 [9] => 84 [10] => 85 [11] => 86 [12] => 87 [13] => 88 [14] => 89 [15] => 90 [16] => 91 [17] => 100 [18] => 179 )
```

I need the parentids of the above categories and their names.

For example:

```
Topcategory 1
 - Subcat 1
 - Subcat 2
 - Subcat 3
 - Subcat 4
 - Subcat 5

Topcategory 2
 - Subcat 6
 - Subcat 7
 - Subcat 8
```

All subcats are in the above array and shown on the product page, but I need the ids of Topcategory 1 and 2 and their names.

Answer (score 1):

To get all categories in magento 1.9.2.4 -

```
<?php  $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category'); $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories(); if (count($_categories) > 0){
    foreach($_categories as $_category){
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($_subcategories) > 0){
            echo $_category->getName();
            echo $_category->getId();      
            foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){
                 echo $_subcategory->getName();
                 echo $_subcategory->getId();
            }
        }
    } } ?>
```

To get a single category we should use -

```
<?php 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4); //4 = categoryID
$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
if (count($subcategories) > 0){
    echo $category->getName();
    foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
         echo $subcategory->getName();
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps :)